# how can I subtract the amount Randint generates in the while loop from enemies HP without getting 2 different numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop

If you run the code you should see that the print says "14" for example, but It retracts something else from enemies HP.

Calculating attack damage for each "spell":

```
from random import randint
import time


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, health):
        self.health = health

    @staticmethod
    def use_heal():
        return randint(9, 21)

    @staticmethod
    def attack_slice():
        return randint(5, 29)

    @staticmethod
    def attack_bash():
        return randint(11, 18)

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, health):
        self.health = health

    @staticmethod
    def enemy_attack():
        return randint(9, 19)
```

For setting HP:

```
player = Player(100)
enemy = Enemy(100)
```

The loop that is the "game":

```
while True:
    print(f"Your hp: {player.health}\nEnemy hp: {enemy.health}\n")
    print("(1) Bash _ (2) Slice _ (3) Heal")
    attack_choice = int(input(">>"))
    
    if attack_choice == 1:
        print(f"You hit for {Player.attack_bash()}")
        enemy.health -= Player.attack_bash()
    
    elif attack_choice == 2:
        print(f"You hit for {Player.attack_slice()}")
        enemy.health -= Player.attack_slice()
    
    elif attack_choice == 3:
        print(f"You heal for {Player.use_heal()}")
        player.health += Player.use_heal()
```

Answer (score 1):

when it calls Player.attack_* it returns a random value to print, and then calls it a second time to actualy damage the enemy so it is likely a defarent value. what it should do is call it once, store it in a variable and use the variable

```
while True:
    print(f"Your hp: {player.health}\nEnemy hp: {enemy.health}\n")
    print("(1) Bash _ (2) Slice _ (3) Heal")
    attack_choice = int(input(">>"))
    
    if attack_choice == 1:
        damage = Player.attack_bash()
        print(f"You hit for {damage}")
        enemy.health -= damage
    
    elif attack_choice == 2:
        damage = Player.attack_slice()
        print(f"You hit for {damage}")
        enemy.health -= damage
    
    elif attack_choice == 3:
        damage = Player.use_heal()
        print(f"You heal for {damage}")
        player.health += damage
```

Comment: AH Thanks. Didn't even think about that :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are generating two random numbers for each case: The one that gets print and the one that gets subtracted/added.

```py
...
print(f"You hit for {Player.attack_bash()}") # Generates a random number
enemy.health -= Player.attack_bash() # Generates another random number
...
```

You need to use a temporary variable so you can use the same value twice:

```py
...
damage = Player.attack_bash()
print(f"You hit for {damage}")
enemy.health -= damage
...
```